# how can we stop front running for `approve`

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, erc-20, attacks

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success)
```

This is the ordinary `ERC20` `approval` method. It's easy to figure out that we have a problem of front-running.

- `Alice` gives allowance of 100 tokens to Bob.
- Later, `Alice` rethinks her choice, changing it to 50. When this happens, Bob watches the chain, transfers his 100 tokens immediatelly with a higher gas price.

As a result, Bob gains 150 tokens overal instead of 50.

How can we avoid the above situation ? can `commit-reveal` help ? if yes, `how` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ERC20 standard as it is cannot solve this problem. Refer to the link below for a proposal to change the ERC20 API to prevent this problem.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YLPtQxZu1UAvO9cZ1O2RPXBbT0mooh4DYKjA_jp-RLM/edit

Commit-reveal is a solution to a front running attack, but its use is slightly different. Even if you commit-reveal your problem, a front running attack is still possible because you have to expose the quantity in reveal.

Comment: let's follow your way. Alice first gave 100 token approval to Bob, and now wants to change it to 50. So Alice submits approve method for 0 amount. Bob sees that and immediatelly, calls transferFrom. His transaction was faster. now, Bob has 100 token. I guess, now, the only advantage with this way is that Alice before approving 50 tokens, checks if meanwhile, Bob spent the previous 100 tokens. Alice will see that Bob spent it so won't do 50 token approval anymore. Is this the right way of thinking ?

Comment: It's just a little better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 transactions

- first approve for zero tokens, wait for that transaction to go through
- approve again for 50 tokens.

Comment: let's follow your way. `Alice` first gave 100 token approval to `Bob`, and now wants to change it to 50. So `Alice` submits approve method for `0` amount. Bob sees that and immediatelly, calls `transferFrom`. His transaction was faster. now, Bob has 100 token. I guess, now, the only advantage with this way is that `Alice` before approving 50 tokens, checks if meanwhile, Bob spent the previous 100 tokens. `Alice` will see that Bob spent it so won't do 50 token approval anymore. Is this the right way of thinking ?